# problem with adding URL variable with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url-modification

I am trying to set and catch the URL variable

It begins with a form which has the standard action set to "/autorisation/logout"
Then a button with an inline JavaScript function

```
function tbPayout()
{
parent.location = "/autorisation/logout?rcgo=payout";
return true;

} 
<input src="/images/go02.gif" type=image border=0 name="go1" onClick="return tbPayout();">
```

In the authorization controller I try to catch it

```
if ( isset($_GET['rcgo']) ) {
```

but it doesn't work and I can't see the variable in the URL and therefore the
default forms action is performed?

I also have another redirect page with:

```
content="3; url=http://www.domain.nl/index/index?rcgo=logout" />
```

and that works fine.

How can I get the JavaScript to work because I have three submit buttons that I need to control by using different URL variables that I need to read in the controller function.
Which is logout() in this case.

It is worth mentioning that is has got something to do with the fact that it can not interpret the variable in the URI because it defaults to the index function off that controller which is the standard behavior if it can't find the second part.
Without the variable attached, it redirects ok.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's as simple as

```
parent.location.href = "/autorisation/logout?rcgo=payout";
```

instead of

```
parent.location = "/autorisation/logout?rcgo=payout";
```

Comment: I found the solution by adding a slash before the questionmark
The problem was that I did not know how the pretty url was being parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using AJAX to pass as GET/POST directly...

```
var queryString = "?rcgo=payout";
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "/autorisation/logout" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

Comment: looks interesting, I will try that also. I am guessing those are basic javascript functions and not jquery?

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxxmlhttprequest.php

Take a look at that to get a better idea how to "build" the ajax object and handle it a bit.